# How can I generate meta tag for react project where I use the laravel api?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I use react for my project but using laravel api.
I can generate meta Tag by react halmet.
But it's didn't work for Facebook scraper or any social share,
Anyone ca give any solution?????

Comment: Whats the link to the site, or view page source and check meta tags

Comment: My guess is that the problem is that because you're generating meta tags with javascript, bots that only inspect html are not discovering your meta tags. Can you generate them in Laravel?

Comment: Please ensure the meta tags are present in head, sometimes due to the page load time scrapers return request timed out, please validate your page against share debuggers provided by the social networks